# Java: Using size() to determine amount of different arrayList entry types

Tags: java, arraylist, size

Is it possible to find the different types of entries within an arraylist using the size() method? For instance I have an arraylist with 2 different types (personal entries, business entries).

I have a numberOfEntries method as:

```
data = new ArrayList<Entry>();

public int numberOfEntries() {
    return data.size();
  }
```

This however counts total entries (personal and business). Is there an easier\better method rather than using the instanceOf and looping around the array that I dont know of?

Comment: Of course it isn't. See the Javadoc. Not a real question.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to extend list for this sole purpose. There are many invariants you have to keep up to date. E.g. you can't just simply override add, you have to override remove too.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your usage and the importance of `data`, you could write a small class that stores the `Entry`s. E.g. in a `Map<Class<?>, List<Entry<?>>>`.

Then you could simply perform sth. like `MyObjectOfClass.getEntriesOfType(Personal.class).size()`.

Answer (score 1):

Short of using a different collection class that separates the two types (which may or may not be appropriate here), no.

You'll have to loop over the array and count. There is nothing "magic" built-in.

You could use libraries like Google Guava, but they'd be doing the same thing under the hood.

Comment: thank you. Just needed to  know that nothing exists really. Will stick with my loop.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. The size() method for ArrayList returns only the number of elements in the List (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/).

Depending on what you are intending on doing , you may want to keep a count of the number of of each type of object (fiddly), or store them in separate Lists (counts are implicit in List size).

Consider how often you need to use the count figures - is it suitable to count each time or track the counts?  Don't worry about efficiency too much if the program is trivial as it will make no difference - focus on correct behaviour first.

If you decide to derive a new data structure for your own purposes, I would wrap the underlying structure with a class implementing only the methods you are likely to need, rather than extending it - this is much less error prone and will restrict the number of methods you will have to override.

Article on avoiding extends:
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2003/jw-0801-toolbox.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't, but it's not hard to implement, you can define a class inheriting  from ArrayList, add a property of type

```
Map<Class,Integer>
```

which collects data that how many objects of the specified type is in this array, then override the add() method, add statistics codes before insert the object

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    // add code here to the collect info
    return super.add(e)
}
```